# Ceramic capacitors soldering "placement/vertical" polarity

Tags: polarity, ceramic, mlcc

I was wondering, since multilayer ceramic caps have layers like this:

[image: mlcc]

[Image source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Typical-multilayer-ceramic-capacitor-MLCC-11_fig5_237520031)

Aren't they supposed to (for better performance) be soldered on the PCB as the above picture shows aka parallel to the PCB layer, for example like this:

[image: paraller mlcc solder]

and NOT vertically like this:

[image: mlcc polarity]

[Image source](https://www.ttieurope.com/content/ttieurope/en/resources/marketeye/categories/tti-insights/me-ray-20201123.html)

(Which I think will also make the layers radiate around the PCB when their power is noisy and has ripple.)

If "Yes," is there a way to tell which side I will be soldering when I solder with soldering iron/oven?

Comment: What performance effect you are talking about, and what would the layers radiate, and if they do radiate something, won't it radiate just as much regardless of how it is mounted?

Comment: I do not know about performance effect, its just a thought of mine. But well lets say someone designs a PCB for a PC CPU or RAM, he/she will use the best practices/ techniques to design the pcb. Wont this play a major role to such fast signals? Since designers go 'crazy' to use thinner pcbs, route their signals only on top layer etc etc, won't capacitor placement play a role as well?

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios "*Since designers go 'crazy' to use thinner pcbs, route their signals only on top layer etc etc*" I doubt any orientation would reduce the parasitic inductance which is the real limiting factor at high frequencies which is why embedded/distributed capacitance PCBs exist. I suspect you don't understand why they do what they do. I've never heard of this only on the top layer business

Comment: Depends in my opinion. Do you see the capacitor as a 'blackbox' or not. For sure some propertys will change if you change the mounting position - but are these changes relevant at all? I can not see any advantages - but i do not have serious education on this topic.

Comment: Since the capacitors come in a reel from manufacturer, I suppose it would not be possible, or at least it would take a special step, to mount them on a different orientation they come from factory reel. They may not be specified for other mounting angles, due to mechanical stress if you flex the PCB. And if you want a better capacitor, you would choose one with terminals on the long sides, not on the short side.

Comment: Given the fact that MLCCs consist of multiple layers which have only a tiny distance to each other, the effect you're describing will be very small. I bet it's negligible compared to parasitic capacitances of tracks, the capacity tolerance of the MLCC itself and changes of capacity caused by temperature changes.

Comment: This question relates to whether or not the plates of the MLCC capacitor should be parallel to the PCB or perpendicular to the PCB when mounted.  There are instances of e-noise created by these capacitors.  I'm not sure why the accepted answer speaks to tombstone which is an SMA defect on any two terminal component. This excerpt references some of the considerations. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7930261

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This defect would be called "tombstone" , when a part mounted on its side or it stands up. Generally it is an indicator of quality of manufacture, but on certain applications the orientation may matter electrically or have poor contact.

MLCC generally mounted automatically from a tape and reel in the orientation that is **most solderable**. A suction nozzle grabs the part and puts it down on the board, the tape and reel technology is designed to have the part in the correct orientation for the automatic equipment.

Occasionally the component  is rotated within the tape and reel , a packaging error, this may result in a poorly mounted part and is caught during inspection

For hand soldering, it is generally pretty easy to tell when side is "down" on the capacitor pancake , but with small parts like 0402 or 0603 it is common to tombstone the part when hand soldering for novices. Usually this is only a mechanical concern, but if you believe that there is an electrical need it only reinforces the interpretation of this as a defect.

Very occasionally the part is "square " (usually high density small sized caps), generally the manufacturer does not indicate the preferred axis and **it would be considered over constraint for you to prefer an axis**, likely for this kind of sensitive application there are specialty caps with asymmetry to have a fixed orientation. (Like a three/four lead  feedthrough capacitor)

Comment: For example, advanced smt will image every part and discard if the mounting head detects the part is picked up sideways by comparing the image against a 3d model of the part :)

Answer (score 0):

I found something, just the thing I was suspicious about.

[image: 4 - PCB antenna impedance matching]

[Source video](https://youtu.be/9fYPQSuUQXc?si=IDQL40--Yzs2wo2s&t=57)

The video doesn't mention anything else but Id like to see such datasheet with a plot about orientation of placement vs L change.

Of course, this is about inductors, the question was about capacitors.